# How to view the omitted output in R software?

Tags: r

In some situations R software purposely omits some results with "..." sign. For example if somebody is drawing an x bar chart or an R chart using `qcc` package R shows only a first few sample means and display "..." sign. Is there any way to see the complete output?

Example:

```
#R code is stated below
library(qcc)
data = matrix(c(32, 28, 39, 50, 42, 50, 44, 22, 37, 32, 52, 42, 45, 
                29, 52, 35, 42, 40, 28, 31, 34, 21, 35, 44), 8, 3, byrow=TRUE)
qcc(data, type="xbar")
# if we run it then the output will be displayed as below
List of 11
$ call : language qcc(data = data͵ type = "xbar")
$ type : chr "xbar"
$ data.name : chr "data"
$ data : num [1:8, 1:3] 32 28 39 50  . . .
$ statistics : Named num [1:8] 37 33.3 39.7 41 . . .
```

How can I view the complete output without "..." signs?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the result of the call to `qcc`. Then you'll notice that the result is of class `qcc`. The printing method for `qcc` objects `print.qcc` actually calls `str`, which is responsible for shortening the result. You can display the whole result with e.g. `unclass`.

```
res <- qcc(data, type="xbar")
unclass(res)
```